# Change content of div when clicked on 1 of 4 small divs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, toggle

I have 4 squares (divs)
And 1 large div where I want the content to be loaded in according to which div is clicked

Kind of like 'the technology' section of http://www.w3.org/html/logo/

How can I do that using javascript/jquery?

First I have to say that I'm really new to jQuery.

EDIT: *this is the fixed version for future reference*

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>

<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />

<style type="text/css">
.square{
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    float: left;
    background: #CCC;
}

#details{
    width: 400px;
    height: 100px;
    float: left;
    background: #999;
}
</style>

<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.square:first').css('background-color', 'red');

    $(".square").on("click", function() {
        $('.square').css('background-color', ' #ccc');
        $(this).css('background-color','red');
        var id= 'Content for div ' + $(this).attr("contentId");
        $('#details').fadeOut(function(){
            $(this).text(id).fadeIn();
        })
    });
});
</script>

</head>

<body>

    <div class="square" contentId="c1"></div>
    <div class="square" contentId="c2"></div>
    <div class="square" contentId="c3"></div>
    <div class="square" contentId="c4"></div>

    <div id="details"></div>

    <div style="display: none" id="c1"> Content for div 1</div>
    <div style="display: none" id="c2"> Content for div 2</div>
    <div style="display: none" id="c3"> Content for div 3</div>
    <div style="display: none" id="c4"> Content for div 4</div>     

</body>

</html>
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ZYw65/)

Comment: this could be done with jQuery, not a big deal of code. but at least post your HTML and where you are going to obtain new content for parent from. Otherwise we can't help with it

Comment: well, you still can post your HTML here, to make it clear for everyone

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    <div class="square" contentId="c1"></div>
    <div class="square" contentId="c2"></div>
    <div class="square" contentId="c3"></div>
    <div class="square" contentId="c4"></div>

    <div id="details"></div>


<div style="display: none" id="c1"> Content for div 1</div>
<div style="display: none" id="c2"> Content for div 2</div>
<div style="display: none" id="c3"> Content for div 3</div>
<div style="display: none" id="c4"> Content for div 4</div>

    <script type="text/javascript">

    $(".square").on("click", function() { 
var id= $(this).attr("contentId");
     $("#details").html($("#" + id).html());
    });

    </script>
```

Comment: Thanks, this helps a lot already :)

Only thing I still don't know about jQuery is how to load a non-displayed div or something into the details div.

Comment: din't get u.. can u be more specific

Comment: Is it possible to have 4 different kinds of content ready in non-displayed divs that I can load into the details div?

Comment: Check your console and tell me there is an error. Check your jquery source paths and all

Comment: Problem totally solved. As I'm new to jQuery I forgot the $(document).ready(function(){ at the beginning of my code

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple example. HTML:

```
<div id='target'>Click something below.</div>
<div class='x'>Badda</div>
<div class='x'>Bing</div>
<div class='x'>Badda</div>
<div class='x'>Boom</div>
```

And then using jQuery:

```
$('.x').click(function() { $('#target').html($(this).html()); });
```

Or you could be a bit more adventurous and do it by decorating your divs with an attribute describing where they should be duplicated to on click.

```
<div id='target'>Click something below.</div>
<div dup_to='target'>Badda</div>
<div dup_to='target'>Bing</div>
<div dup_to='target'>Badda</div>
<div dup_to='target'>Boom</div>
```

Then...(no jQuery here but it needs querySelectorAll, you could do it with a simple loop or class name as well):

```
elems = document.querySelectorAll('[dup_to]');

for (i = 0; i < elems.length; ++i) 
{
  elems[i].onclick = dup_content_to(elems[i].getAttribute('dup_to'));   
}

function dup_content_to(target)
{
    return function() { document.getElementById(target).innerHTML = this.innerHTML; };
}
```

(Hurrah for over-engineering.)

Comment: I agree with avoiding jquery and using pure javascript. queryselector supports almost all the jquery selectors. :)